# Oracle Bulk Data Processing

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle19c

Can anyone give me any insight into why my benchmarking for Oracle Bulk Data Processing be giving no gains at all for INSERTS and UPDATES, but massive (400-500%) gains for DELETE operations?

I'm using a small set of data for testing: 2000 records. Times are in the 0.02 second -1.1 second range.

Here is some code you can use to test:

```sql
create table tmp$_t1 (id number generated by default on null as identity primary key, c1 varchar2 (30), c2 varchar2 (30))
/

set timing on serveroutput on size unlimited linesize 32767 pagesize 50000 trimspool on tab off feedback on
define svTableName = tmp$_t1
define svInsertHowMany = 2000
define svUpdateWhichMod = 2
define svDeleteWhichMod = 10
truncate table &svTableName
/
<<s01_row_by_row_rbr_dml>> begin <<rbr_loop>> for iRec in (select dbms_random.string ('p', 10) c1 from dual connect by level <= &svInsertHowMany) loop
          insert into &svTableName (c1) values (iRec.c1); end loop rbr_loop; commit;
     <<update_loop>> for iUpdateRec in (select id, c1 from &svTableName) loop
          update &svTableName set c2 = substr (c1, 1, 2) || ' ## ' || id where mod (id, &svUpdateWhichMod) = 0 and id = iUpdateRec.id; end loop update_loop; commit;
     <<delete_loop>> for iDeleteRec in (select id, c1 from &svTableName) loop
          delete &svTableName where mod (id, &svDeleteWhichMod) = 0; end loop delete_loop; commit;
     end s01_row_by_row_rbr_dml;
/
undefine svInsertHowMany svFetchRate svUpdateWhichMod svDeleteWhichMod

set timing on serveroutput on size unlimited linesize 32767 pagesize 50000 trimspool on tab off feedback on
define svTableName = tmp$_t1
define svInsertHowMany = 2000
define svFetchRate = 100000
define svUpdateWhichMod = 2
define svDeleteWhichMod = 10
truncate table &svTableName
/
<<s02_obdp_dml>> declare
     cursor cOBDP is select dbms_random.string ('p', 10) c1 from dual connect by level < &svInsertHowMany; type tOBDP is table of cOBDP%rowtype; lOBDP tOBDP;
     cUpdateDelete sys_refcursor; type tOBDPRec is table of &svTableName%rowtype; lOBDPRec tOBDPRec;
     begin open cOBDP; fetch cOBDP bulk collect into lOBDP limit &svFetchRate;
     <<OBDP_loop>> loop forall iOBDPRec in lOBDP.first .. lOBDP.last insert into &svTableName (c1) values (lOBDP (iOBDPRec).c1);
          fetch cOBDP bulk collect into lOBDP limit &svInsertHowMany; exit when cOBDP%notfound; end loop OBDP_loop; close cOBDP; commit;
          open cUpdateDelete for select * from &svTableName; fetch cUpdateDelete bulk collect into lOBDPRec limit &svFetchRate;
          <<update_delete_loop>> loop forall iOBDPRec in lOBDPRec.first .. lOBDPRec.last update &svTableName
                    set c2 = substr (c1, 1, 2) || ' ## ' || trim (to_char (lOBDPRec (iOBDPRec).id))
                    where mod (lOBDPRec (iOBDPRec).id, &svUpdateWhichMod) = 0 and id = lOBDPRec (iOBDPRec).id;
               forall iOBDPRec in lOBDPRec.first .. lOBDPRec.last delete &svTableName where mod (lOBDPRec (iOBDPRec).id, &svDeleteWhichMod) = 0 and id = lOBDPRec(iOBDPRec).id;
               fetch cUpdateDelete bulk collect into lOBDPRec limit &svFetchRate; exit when cUpdateDelete%notfound;
               end loop update_delete_loop; close cUpdateDelete; commit;
     end s02_obdp_dml;
/
undefine svInsertHowMany svFetchRate svUpdateWhichMod svDeleteWhichMod
```

The second anonymous block there contains INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE operations, which will be timed in aggregate.

In order to test only the INSERT, only the UPDATE or only the DELETE, simply comment out the code respectively, and rerun.

I have it all as separate blocks, but that's just a ton of code, maybe. I'm thinking so anyway.

RBR = "Row by Row", and OBDP = "Oracle Bulk Data Processing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is pretty good but you need to increase the number of runs or the number of rows to see more meaningful results. When I increased the number of rows inserted from 2K to 200K, I got the below run times in seconds. These results clearly imply that bulk processing is faster for inserts.

```
Test               Run 1   Run 2   Run 3   Run 4   Run 5
=================  ======  ======  ======  ======  ======
Row-by-row insert  15.086  14.862  15.025  14.868  14.946
Bulk insert         3.915   3.958   3.919   3.745   3.826
```

When run times are too small, random system activity can account for a large percentage of the total run time. There's always some gremlin in the system just waiting to slow down an otherwise fast running query. Maybe the shared pool just got cleared and spiked the CPU for a second, or the anti-virus program just started, etc.

You need to be extra careful if you're going to thoroughly test bulk collection. The Internet is littered with (unintentionally) fabricated test results that make bad claims. This is because most testers are not familiar with the [simple mathematical underpinnings of bulk collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38664103/409172). A lot of results perfectly match a `1/N` curve, but only until the test just so happens to get to the part where the testers *think* the results should be more linear. If you only run your tests once or twice, you may be tempted to believe in a statistical aberration.

Comment: @John could you possibly explain what is meant by "1/N" curve and "linear results"? Thank you.

Comment: I am reading this resource: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution but I'm not sure this is what you're referring to. I'm thinking it may be simpler than this!!

Comment: @M.Kemp If you plot the amount of overhead of row-by-row operations (Y) against the batch size (X), the result looks like the graph Y=1/X. (See my linked answer for a sample graph.) The graph is a curve where the amount of overhead (Y) quickly approaches zero for even a small batch size (X). But there is a small part of that graph that *looks* like a straight line. A lot of people only measure that initial straight-line performance increase and come to a wrong conclusion. (Normal distribution has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!! Excellent explanation, for which I am very grateful.